# Preencher textview android studio/sql server

Tags: java, android, sql-server, nullpointerexception

Boas malta,
não tou a conseguir preencher uma textview recorrendo a uma base de dados sql server. Alguem me consegue ajudar? Eis o que tenho no onCreate:

```
connectionClass = new MainActivity();
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

Connection con = connectionClass.connectionclass(connectionClass.ut, connectionClass.pw, connectionClass.db, connectionClass.server);
String query = "select text from Org";

try {

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();


} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xde4f60e0
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xde4f62a0
E/error here 1 :: Unknown server host name 'Host is unresolved: null'.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.EnterpriseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
      at EnterpriseActivity.onCreate(EnterpriseActivity.java:33)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta não precisa da tag `sql-server` por se tratar de uma questão de java.

Comment: Faz tempo que não abro um Eclipse da vida (C# tomou conta da minha vida), mas tenta entrar em modo debug e vê o que o objeto `con` recebe logo após a instanciação.

Answer (score 2):

Após ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();

```
while(rs.next()){
   text.setText(rs.getString("text"));
}
```

Testa ai e diz se funcionou

Comment: Não funcionou, a app deixa de funcionar quando tento abrir a activity...

Comment: Qual a mensagem e erro?